# Only the desktop version of a website looks as it is supposed to on mobile

Tags: android, html, css

I have been designing a website so that it looks good on different resolutions. I tested it by resizing the Firefox window width and the website responded as expected. I was happy until friends gave me the feedback that it looks suboptimally on mobile, which is true.
When looked at on mobile, there are several issues which I cannot understand:

- it looks magnified.
- the background does not fill but rather scrolls along to certain limits when I scroll
- animated text gradients don't work under chrome but they do under firefox,

These two screenshots show the difference, the correct/expected mobile version on the right:
[image: the correct mobile version on the right]
I dont see any reason why it seems zoomed on the left. Moreover, when I zoom out, there is a wihte space on the right which makes no sense and which doesnt get away when I zoom in again. Also, zooming out doesnt decrease the font size or anything. Looks like this on both mobile Firefox and mobile Chrome, except on FF the gradient animation works. I wrote all the code myself, no bootstrap.

Help me understand what's happening here and how to design responsively, which I thought I had done :(

```html
.bodyBG {
    background: url(../images/bodyBG.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.animatedGradientTextOrange {
  --bg-size: 400%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
  90deg,
  var(--ueberschriftSattesGelb),
  white,
  var(--ueberschriftSattesGelb)
)
0 0 / var(--bg-size) 100%;
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .animatedGradientTextOrange { animation: move-bg 9s linear infinite; }
  @keyframes move-bg { to { background-position: var(--bg-size) 0; }  }
}

.respText115Bis140{
font-size: clamp(1.15em, 2.4vw, 1.4em);
}
```

Comment: Hello, what looks like your viewport on your html file ? : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` try to put it at `initial-scale=1.0`

Comment: have it exactly like this :/